# Do I have to inform the hotel about my lateness for check in?

Tags: bookings, hotels, check-in

It's my first time to personally book a room, and I'm a little bit confused with the notion of "check in".

Let's say I am supposed to arrive at the hotel on Aug. 15th @ 01:00 am (**the room is fully paid for all of planned night**) whose check in time is 03:00 pm. Then, if I doesn't book Aug. 14th, I have to wait 14 hours till the check in time (!); however, if I book Aug. 14th, as well, then I can directly get to the hotel at 01:00 am.

But I do not know whether I must inform the hotel about this plan or not, because some people say if you don't be at the hotel some time around the check in time (say mostly one hour later), they will maybe give your room to another one.

Is it true?! I mean, I have already paid the price for Aug. 14th; why do I have to inform the hotel about my lateness?

Comment: Probably related: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/99360/what-constitutes-a-late-check-in-for-a-hotel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Do I have to inform the hotel about my lateness for check in?

Usually Yes.

> However, if I book Aug. 14th, as well, then I can directly get to the hotel at 01:00 am.

For that **early** check in, you must usually book a day in advance, just like you have mentioned. However on that booking it does not hurt to mention to the hotel that you will be arriving at 1 AM in the morning on the next day.

> why do I have to inform the hotel about my lateness?

This is usually very important as not all the hotels have check-in desks 24/7. If you don't inform them in advance and they don't have a check-in desk round the clock you might have to sit the night out in the lobby. Even though they know that you have paid for the room already so it is unlikely that you will be denied a room for turning up late, there needs to be someone who can check you in. And that's only one of the reasons, there are more.

I have done so many times and have never faced a problem, just don't surprise them by showing up at 1 am without a prior notice.